# How to mix c# with BIML?

Tags: c#, biml

I have a BIML file, including C# scripts to get a sql string from SQL server, and a BIML project parameter that can customize the sql string, coded as below:

```
<Projects>
    <PackageProject Name="ProjectSSIS60">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="pTenantKey" Id="{3f8e0fe6-e8c4-4a6a-8fb3-ddf6bbeb63a6}" DataType="Int16">123</Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </PackageProject>
</Projects>

<Packages>
    <#
    foreach(DataRow row in AllTables.Rows)
    {
        SqlSource = row["SqlSource"].ToString();
    #>
        <Package Name="LoadDim" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="Dim">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="pConnectionOLTP" Name="SRC Dim">
                            <DirectInput><#=SqlSource.Replace("@[$Project::pTenantKey]", ProjectSSIS60::pTenantKey)#></DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
```

... ...

I want to use

```
<#=SqlSource.Replace("@[$Project::pTenantKey]", ProjectSSIS60::pTenantKey)#>
```

to replace the keyword `@[$Project::pTenantKey]` inside returned sql string with the project parameter `ProjectSSIS60::pTenantKey`.

However the error message shows that

> Alias 'ProjectSSIS60' not found

. 
How can I refer a project parameter in C# string please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I remove the project scope, i,e, change ProjectSSIS60::pTenantKey to pTenantKey only, the error is read as: The name 'pTenantKey' does not exist in the current context

Comment: BIML files are XML format so you can use XML methods.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge I think you are running into is twofold.

The first is that you have declared the Project Parameter within the scope of the current Biml tier and so you cannot reference it, yet.

The second is that you are mixing evaluation contexts. If the Replace operation did work, then you would create an SSIS package with a hard coded reference to the current value of the project's parameter.

Instead, I believe what your `SqlSource` looks like is something along the lines of

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MyTable AS T
WHERE T.TenantKey = @[$Project::pTenantKey]
```

If that is the case, you have mixed the parameterization types around - easy to do.

You've specified this is an OLEDB Source so you will use a zero ordinal based system with `?` as the place holder/token.  The above string should become

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MyTable AS T
WHERE T.TenantKey = ?
```

You will then modify OleDbSource to have a `<Parameters>` section and it'd look something like

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="0" VariableName="@[$Project::pTenantKey]" />
</Parameters>
```

As long as the place holder is either in the SELECT or the WHERE clause, this should work.

You cannot, however, parameterize the source table ala FROM `dbo.?`
If you need that sort of dynamism, then you need to use an SSIS Variable to hold your source query and apply an Expression to it such that you manually replace the token with the current value of the project parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, that does make sense to me.
However my problem of using question mark technique is that my project needs to handle multiple packages with a different SqlSource row for each. In this case I cannot always have the parameter bounding
<Parameter Name="0" VariableName="@[$Project::pTenantKey]" />
Because some packages do not need this parameter in OleDBSource, and others can have it after several other parameters. Therefore I hope to replace the returned SqlSource by keywords that match the defined project parameters.